# Which scripture mentions the verse "Chandalohpi munisrestha haribhaktiparayanah..."?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, caste-system, bhakti

> *Chandalohapi munisrestha haribhaktiparayanah |
>  Haribhaktivihinashcha dviijohapi shvapachadhamah ||*

> **English Translation**: Chandalas with Hari Bhakti are superior to Munis. But if a Dvija is devoid of Hari Bhakti then he is worse than even a Chandala.

I found the above verse mentioned in Hari Lilamrita, the biography of Sri Sri Harichand Thakur, founder of the non-Vedic Matua Vaishnava Sampradaya, written in Bengali:

[image]

But it doesn't seem to be originally from that book. A friend of mine believes it's from the Hari Bhakti Vilasa but I haven't been able to find it so far.

So which text originally mentions the above verse?

Comment: I have given the full verse upon seeing the pic you have uploaded. Previously the full verse wasn't given.

Comment: Probably I have read it in Brihan Naradiya Purana but I don't have this book with me any longer so unable to verify.

Comment: Ah thanks and no problem :) @Rickross

Comment: A verse with similiar meaning is quoted in [this](https://narayanastra.blogspot.com/p/on-symbols-and-practices-of-vaishnavism.html?m=0) article from vasishta smriti.// caturvedī ca yo vipro vāsudevaṃ na vindati ।
vedabhārabharākrāntaḥ sa vai brāhmaṇagardabhaḥ//  Meaning:The brAhmaNa who is well-versed in the four Vedas, but undevoted to Vasudeva, is a Veda-carrying donkey that happens to be a brAhmaNa.

Comment: Southern recension of Mahabharata has another verse in similiar tone,apArthakaM prabhAShantaH shUdrA bhAgavatA iti.
na shUdrA bhagavadbhaktA viprA bhAgavatAH smR^itAH.. 14-118-32. Meaning:AswamedhikA parvA (118.32) : "Those sUdrAs who have
devotion to BhagavAn are not sUdrAs ; they who are devotees of BhagavAn
are Brahmins. Those who have no bhakti to BhagavAn (JanArdanA) , whatever 
might be his caste - they alone are sUdrAs "